# FlexiDB Inserting 1000 rows is slow, how can I speed it up?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, nosql, database-server

I am using FlexiDB Server, when I insert 1000 rows using the command below it takes some time:

```
$.collection('collection_name').insert(row);
```

How can this be accelerated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command insert_bulk, create an array to hold all of your objects and then use the command insert_bulk to insert all at once.

```
$.collection('collection_name').insert_bulk(rows);
```